# Purpose of the second argument in tuple within receive...end. statement?

Tags: erlang, arguments, tuples

The snippet shown below from this [page](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/static/erlang/linkmon.erl) illustrates the use of sending messages and one of the things I have trouble making sense of is the second argument within the receive clause for the `judge(Pid, Band, Album) ->` function call where `{Pid, Criticism} -> Criticism`?

What is the purpose of the variable `Criticism`?

Heres the snippet:

```
start_critic() ->
   spawn(?MODULE, critic, []).

judge(Pid, Band, Album) ->
   Pid ! {self(), {Band, Album}},
    receive
     {Pid, Criticism} -> Criticism
    after 2000 ->
     timeout
end.

critic() ->
   receive
     {From, {"Rage Against the Turing Machine", "Unit Testify"}} ->
        From ! {self(), "They are great!"};
     {From, {"System of a Downtime", "Memoize"}} ->
        From ! {self(), "They're not Johnny Crash but they're good."};
     {From, {"Johnny Crash", "The Token Ring of Fire"}} ->
        From ! {self(), "Simply incredible."};
     {From, {_Band, _Album}} ->
        From ! {self(), "They are terrible!"}
end,
critic().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine we have an `erlang:receive/0` function that picks the *first* message in the mailbox and returns it. We could then rewrite the `receive` as follows*:

```
case erlang:receive() of
    {Pid, Criticism} ->
        Criticism
end.
```

The point here is that the `receive`expression can be thought of as a variant of `case` that takes its input from the process mailbox. Thus, we can use pattern matching to decompose the message like we would any other term in a `case` expression.

When the sender uses the send (`!`) operator to pass a message to the process, the message (any Erlang term) is basically copied into the process mailbox, from which it can be retrieved using `receive`.

*Note that our imaginary `receive/0` provides no facility to skip over messages that don't match the desired pattern, nor does it accommodate timeouts. Also, if the message doesn't match any of the case clauses, the process will crash with a `case_clause` error. This is not the case with the ordinary `receive`expression.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a second argument, it's just part of the received message. Read about pattern matching e.g. [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions) or [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Erlang_Programming/Pattern_Matching), since it's a very important concept in Erlang.

When some process with PID `P1` does `From ! {self(), "Simply incredible."}` and `From` is a PID of a process running `judge`, then `{P1, "Simply incredible."}` is matched against the pattern `{Pid, Criticism}`, so that `Pid` is bound to `P1`, and `Criticism` is bound to `"Simply incredible."`.